# how to create a swig custom typemap for std::set to be wrapped by native python set?

Tags: swig

The default typemap provided by swig expects a python list as input for constructing a set instead of native Python set (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775791/why-swig-casts-python-list-to-stdvector-seamlessly-and-not-stdset/60818177#60818177)). Indeed,

```
%include "std_set.i"
%template(IntSet) std::set<int>;
```

will trigger the following behavior in python:

```
>>> import MyClass
>>> MyClass.IntSet([1,2,3,4]) # works
>>> MyClass.IntSet({1,2,3,4}) # does not work
```

I tried to create a custom typemap to do so but I failed so far. Here my current swig file to do so:

```
%module MyClass

%{
    #include "MyClass.h"
%}

%include <typemaps.i>

%typemap(in) setin {$1 = PySequence_List($input);}
%typemap(out) setout {$result = PySet_New($1);}

%include "std_set.i"
%template(IntSet) std::set<int>;

%include "MyClass.h"
```

Would you know how to make it ?